# Visual Studio 2008 C# project now can't find my references -- likely causes?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reference

I'm using VS 2008.  In one of our web projects, for some reason, I'm suddenly getting yellow exclamation marks indicating missing references.  I'm not sure why.

If I look at the .csproj file in a text editor the references in question are in the project folder structure, tucked in a subfolder, and sure enough that folder and supporting files are there, as they always have been.

Here's a sample of one of the troublesome references, as shown in two places (the only two) in the project file where it's mentioned:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.20820.30875, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e, processorArchitecture=MSIL"/>


<Content Include="ThirdParty\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" />
```

There is a ThirdParty folder in the project, and the appropriate version of AjaxControlToolkit.dll is in there.  The project's settings haven't changed, to my knowledge, so I'm at a loss why all these references are supposedly missing.  Would anyone know how I might diagnose this?

Comment: Check that the assembly version did not change. Also, did you happen to move your solution? I keep forgetting if the relative project references are based on the project or the solution folder...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest/quickest thing to do is remove/re-add the reference.

Would be interested to know what happened, though.

Comment: For some odd reason, when I add any new reference or remove / re-add an existing one, I get the same yellow exclamation point.

Comment: When you say "any new reference," do you mean any reference to these libraries? Or any reference to any library on this project? And is anyone else on the team having this problem with the project? What about, for testing purposes, creating a new project and adding a ref to these probematic assemblies. Do those references work?

Comment: This happens with any reference, including System.* ones.  I agree this is very strange, and I'll be trying the new project idea.  If I do figure this out I'll be sure to post back here.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this was due to some instability in my system-- when I closed VS and reopened the project, things worked just fine.